# Ruby error on OS X Yosemite and chef

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

Getting this error when trying to install chef on OS X Yosemite, other gems have installed fine. Not seeing a requirement. Just wondering if anyone has and idea of what the issue is or has come across this.

```
$sudo gem install chef
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing chef:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141023-4708-6api21.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/libyajl2-1.1.0/ext/libyajl2
extconf.rb:104:in `makemakefiles': unhandled exception
    from extconf.rb:138:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

EDIT: Although my answer below will help you install it on the system version of Ruby. I would probably suggest using RVM instead as the comment below mentions. I do not use Ruby very often and it would probably be fine, but I decided to take the 10 mins to change it to installing to RVM since that way I leave the system ruby untouched.

Comment: You do understand that by using `sudo` you installed Chef into your Apple-supplied Ruby, which is there for their use, right? Perhaps you should look into using [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), rather than modify the system Ruby?

Comment: I don't actually do a lot of Ruby dev. I don't know if I agree with the statement for their use, more system use, but i understand what you are getting at. Mostly just use it for Chef. But thanks for the tip. Maybe I will use RVM incase I venture further down the ruby path.

Comment: Yes, system use. Too many people who have no idea why it would be there assume it was put there for their use only, then mess with it and break it.

Comment: After your comment. even though I do not use my Ruby environment much so I wasn't too worried about breaking it, I decided to take 10 mins to uninstall and setup RVM and re-install. Pretty quick and now if I decide to do more ruby dev I'm better off. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

As I was searching across the web, I could actually resolve this issue (which also appeared on docker/ubuntu) as suggested in this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32191707/1948319

Long story short: The `gmp` library is missing. You can install it on ubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with this gem specifically, and another gem with c extensions as well.

Turns out I needed to accept new terms & conditions after updating XCode :-)

`sudo xcodebuild -license`

Answer (score 0):

So I actually answered my own question very shortly after I posted and I hope it helps someone else in the future.

I used this instead:

```
$ sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install chef
```

> The Apple LLVM compiler in Xcode treats unrecognized command-line options as errors. This issue has been seen when building both Python native extensions and Ruby Gems, where some invalid compiler options are currently specified.

Came across this issue which was similar enough:
https://github.com/FontCustom/fontcustom/issues/194