# Can not install json gem with ruby 2.2.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am going through a Rails tutorial and I'm not able to complete 'bundle install' due to a problem with the json gem.  When I attempt to install it directly:

```
me@tru2:~/rails/hello_app$ gem install json -v '1.8.3'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3-dev/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150820-12793-qdkev7.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [generator.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3-dev/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3-dev/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
```

As mentioned the ruby version is 2.2.3.

```
me@tru2:~/rails/hello_app$ ruby --version
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
```

Running 'gem list' shows that json 1.8.1 is currently installed but something in the default Gemfile must require 1.8.3.  A search showed many similar questions but no answers that got me past this issue.  I have tried running with sudo and it appears to work but going back to me the issue is still there.

Answer (score 146):

`cannot find -lgmp` means that it can't find the gmp library. Try running:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

https://github.com/flori/json/issues/253

Comment: Fixed it for me, when the exact same configuration explained in the question

Comment: Why `libgmp3-dev`? `json-1.8.3` depends on `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so`, which is in [`libgmp-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libgmp-dev/filelist).

Comment: Actually, it's not `json`, that depends on `libgmp`. It's binary `ruby` (precompiled) being built with `libgmp` being present, which makes it required for all the native extensions. This issue doesn't manifest itself with `ruby` being compiled from sources.

Comment: any idea how to do this with centos? cant find the package with yum

Answer (score 4):

Json 1.8.3 seems to have some issues with Ruby 2.2.3 (though I expect some future patches of Ruby will probably fix the problem). Downgrading Ruby to 2.2.2 worked for me.

(That said, so did `sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev`, as [@alf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512507/alf) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32191707/1157242) - but if you're not able to do that, downgrading ruby might be a feasible alternative.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Okay - can anyone else who downvotes this leave a comment to tell me *why* it's not useful please? I've already edited it twice. Thanks

Comment: I disagree, this does provide an answer to the question. The OP is saying, "I can't install X library with Y version of Ruby", and this answer says "change your ruby version."

Answer (score 0):

Try running `rvm implode` and then following this guide http://ryanbigg.com/2014/10/ubuntu-ruby-ruby-install-chruby-and-you/

I suspect RVM did not include the correct headers for you.

Comment: Thank you this got me much further.  I am getting an error with the debugger gem but I suppose I can comment that out and deal with it if I find I need it.

Comment: You should try the `pry` gem instead of the `debugger` gem. It's worked for me on every Ruby version.